# django many-to-many show human-readable in form

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have these models:

```
CURSES=(('python','Python'),('django','Django'),...)
class Asig(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CURSES)

class Profesor(AbstractUser):
    ...
    asigs = models.ManyToManyField(Asig)
```

Then, when I render the form using ModelForm the many-to-many field shows itself with 'python' string instead 'Python', also, when I look the rendered html coded the multiselect options look like:

```
<option value='1'>python</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value='python'>Python</option>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the value 'Python' in the model's `__str__`, method, then you should use `self.get_name_display()` instead of `self.name`:

```
class Asig(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CURSES)

    def __str__(self):  
        # use @python_2_unicode_compatible or define __unicode__ if using Python 2
        return self.get_name_display()
```

You can't easily change many-to-many field to use `value='python'` instead of `value='1'` (the primary key). That's just the way many-to-many fields work.

Comment: get_name_display() it's about the field name? if my field name were flowers then could be get_flowers_display()?

Comment: That's correct. See the docs on [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) for more info.